# Failed push but git status shows nothing to commit

Tags: git

I have pushed to a specific branch, but the push failed due to an oversized file.

As a result, when I am inspecting the corresponding branch on Github, nothing new has been added.

The problem is that locally when I `git status` I get `On branch <branch> nothing to commit, working directory clean` though obviously my local and remote repos are different now.

I have tried to modify a single file from the last changes, and I can see that now `git status` shows it as modified, yet the other files that were failed to be pushed are still not appearing in the `git status` output.

How can I make my local git repository "refresh" its inspection of changes relative to the origin?

Comment: Did you add the files for the commit with `git add *`?

Comment: Git push pushes already made commits, git status shows information about things yet to be committed, they're different things. Git status should also tell you that you're ahead of the remote though.

Comment: It doesn't say I'm ahead - and I commited using `git add .`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't tried what @Tim Biegeleisen offered.

Finally I solved this with

1. `git reset --soft HEAD^`
2. Then, `git status` showed all the files previously staged
3. Then I went on to use `git reset <filename>` to the oversized files
4. `git push origin <branch>` to push the changes remaining.

Comment: I was going to suggest this, but amending the commit should also work here +1.

Comment: Note that (at least in this case, a non-merge commit), when you `git reset --soft HEAD^`, made these changes to the index (`git reset <filename>` for instance is the same as `git rm --cached <filename>` in this case—both remove the large file from the index since it's no longer in `HEAD`), then made a new commit, you did in three steps the same thing Tim Beigeleisen's answer would have done in two.

Answer (score 2):

If you have committed your work, then rightfully Git *should* be telling you `On branch <branch> nothing to commit, working directory clean`.  The issue here is that your push failed and now you have a local commit that you cannot push.

Given that no one else has yet seen this commit, I would recommend removing the too large to push file from being tracked, then amending your commit via:

```
git rm --cached filename
git commit --amend
```

Git commit amend will *rewrite* the commit at the HEAD of your branch, discarding the old one in the process.

Then, try pushing again:

```
git push origin your_branch
```

Comment: What does ammend do? and how would I remove the files from the tracked files if I do not see them on `git status` ?

Comment: Just do what you would sensibly think to do.  Delete the problem files, but then do `git commit --amend` instead of just committing.

Comment: I do not want to delete these files, I just want them to be ignored, I have already added them to .gitignore

Comment: @bluesummers Sorry, I didn't understand your requirement.  Use `git rm --cached` on the file(s), and then amend the commit.

Comment: I've solved it using my answer just before you editted your question - could be that your solution does work I just haven't tried it. Thanks anyway :)